# Why is my prototype function not returning the property of the instance?

Tags: javascript

I have a simple object in Javascript.

> function myClass(x,y) {
>
> ```
> this.x = x;
>
> this.y = y;
> ```
>
> }

and a prototype function

> myClass.prototype.myfunction = function() {
>
> console.log(this.x);
>
> }

and in my main script,

> var x = 2; var y = 4;
>
> myinstance = new myClass(x,y);
>
> myinstance.myfunction();

Instead of receiving x, I get undefined instead. Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the `new` keyword:

```
myinstance = new myClass(x,y);
```

I tried the code, and with that addition it works.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the `new` operator, `myinstance` is `undefined`.

```
var x = 2; var y = 4;

myinstance = new myClass(x,y);
myinstance.myfunction(); // will show `2` in the console
```

**Edit:** Since you say that you are using the `new` operator, I think you might be executing  `myinstance.myfunction();` at the console and you may be looking at the result (return value) of that method, which is actually `undefined`, because it doesn't contain a `return` statement.

See a working example [here](http://jsbin.com/itadi/edit).

Comment: correction - I am using the new operator in my actual code. sorry for missing that out. still getting the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do `myinstance = new myClass(x,y);`

Answer (score 0):

hmm ... try to instanciate your function like this

`var myClass = function (x,y) {`

```
this.x = x;
this.y = y;
this.myfunction = function(){
    console.log(this.x);
}
```

}

this worked quite fine for me