# Initializing new instances of a class in a loop, how can I persist an assignment to an event handler?

Tags: javascript

This is a follow on question from [Why is my prototype function not returning the property of the instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020960/why-is-my-prototype-function-not-returning-the-property-of-the-instance)

> $.getJSON(myjson, function(data) {

```
        var json = data;
        for (i in json) {
            juuvies[i] = new Juuvy(i,json[i], font, keyfontsize, valfontsize, orbcol, orbkeycol, orbvalcol, paper);
            juuvies[i].juuv_it();
            var mykey = juuvies[i].init_nodes();
                            juuvies[i].orb.node.onmouseover = function() { console.log(mykey);};
        }
    });
```

And my init_nodes function,

> Juuvy.prototype.init_nodes = function() {
>           return this.key;
>       }

At this point of time, I get only the last key in the loop, instead of a unique pass each time. Is there a way I can persist the assignment for the event handler?

Comment: This is a really common problem, see these [related questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript+closures+loops)

Comment: Thanks CMS, will have a look. I'm still green in these areas, having difficulty trying to frame the question.

Answer (score 1):

The scope of the `mykey` variable is the function. When the onmouseover event is triggered (which happens after the loop) the event handler uses the value in the variable, which is what it was when it exited the loop.

Use an anonymous function to create a closure that contains the variable:

```
$.getJSON(myjson, function(data) {
  var json = data;
  for (i in json) {
    juuvies[i] = new Juuvy(i,json[i], font, keyfontsize, valfontsize, orbcol, orbkeycol, orbvalcol, paper);
    juuvies[i].juuv_it();
    (function(){
      var mykey = juuvies[i].init_nodes();
      juuvies[i].orb.node.onmouseover = function() { console.log(mykey); };
    })();
  }
});
```

This way the `mykey` variable is a new local variable for each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a closure

```
var json = data;
for (i in json) {
    juuvies[i] = new Juuvy(i,json[i], font, keyfontsize, valfontsize, orbcol, orbkeycol, orbvalcol, paper);
    juuvies[i].juuv_it();
    var mykey = juuvies[i].init_nodes();
    (function(i, mykey){
        juuvies[i].orb.node.onmouseover = function() {
            console.log(mykey);};
        };
    })(i, mykey);
});
```